# Ionic | "TypeError: this.platform.is is not a function when running unit tests

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-jasmine

When I run unit tests for an Ionic project I'm working on, I'm getting this error from AppComponent, and it happens on two unit tests:

```
App component should create the app

TypeError: this.platform.is is not a function
```

and

```
App component should initialize the app

TypeError: this.platform.is is not a function
```

Here is the code for my app.component.spec.ts:

```js
import { HttpClientTestingModule} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NativeAudio } from '@ionic-native/native-audio/ngx';
import { Dialogs } from '@ionic-native/dialogs/ngx';
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm/ngx';

describe('AppComponent', () => {

  let statusBarSpy, splashScreenSpy, platformReadySpy, platformSpy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    statusBarSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('StatusBar', ['styleDefault']);
    splashScreenSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SplashScreen', ['hide']);
    platformReadySpy = Promise.resolve();
    platformSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Platform', { ready: platformReadySpy });
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ HttpClientTestingModule ],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: StatusBar, useValue: statusBarSpy },
        { provide: SplashScreen, useValue: splashScreenSpy },
        { provide: Platform, useValue: platformSpy },
        { provide: NativeStorage },
        { provide: Router },
        { provide: NativeAudio },
        { provide: Dialogs },
        { provide: FCM }
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should initialize the app', async () => {
    TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    expect(platformSpy.ready).toHaveBeenCalled();
    await platformReadySpy;
    expect(statusBarSpy.styleDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(splashScreenSpy.hide).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Here is the code that is supposedly causing the error:

```
    if (this.platform.is('cordova') || this.platform.is('desktop') || this.platform.is('mobile')) {
        this.storageEngine = this.localStorage;
    } else {
        this.storageEngine = this.storage;
    }
```

When I was looking up this error, the only solution I was able to find was to create a mock object for Platform, but I already have one. Anyone have any idea how I may be able to fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is giving you the answer. You have mocked ready but you have not mocked the 'is' function.

Try this.

```
platformSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Platform', { ready: platformReadySpy, 
is: (type: string) => { 
     if (type === 'cordova' || type === 'desktop' || type === 'mobile') {
       return true; 
     } else { 
       return false; 
     } 
   }
});
```